# Gridviews and datascources

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

I have this bit of code that is populating my gridview with a csv file. I need to hide some columns but do not know where in the code to proceed with this.I really need help with this, so please avoid commenting about how I presented to you or giving me a minus because my grammar is not good.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Configuration;

 namespace SeccurisCsvReader
 {
    public partial class gridView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }   

     protected void csvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == string.Empty)
         {
             lblMsg.Visible = true;
             return;
         }
         else
         {
             string[] FileExt = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.');
             string FileEx = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1];
             if (FileEx.ToLower() == "csv")
             {
                 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" " + FileUpload1.FileName));
             }
             else
             {
                 lblMsg.Visible = true;
                 return;
             }
         }
         CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
         string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

         foreach (string strHeader in headers)
             dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
        string[] data;
         while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
             dt.Rows.Add(data);
         CsvGridView.DataSource = dt;           
         CsvGridView.DataBind();


             }
         }


     }

 Now where do I start!!!
```

Comment: You should apply your filter here: `while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null) dt.Rows.Add(data);`

Comment: Could you show me an example please, I have been trying to work this out for couple days now. My head is about to exploded.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to omit entire columns of the table from being shown. Rather than figuring out what not to read in the first place, which you should do if you have no use for that data at all, you can define what the grid view shows without altering your table at all. That way if you need the other information and simply don't want to show it it will still be there in the row so you can find it and use it.

You want to define your columns within the grid view and specify which columns in the table they use

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="you_will_want_to_name_your_column" HeaderText="column name" ShowHeader="true"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

is a start, I assume you are in visual studio, so I am betting intelli-sense will show you the rest.

Also [Grid View Column Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx#column_fields) will teach you about column types and data binding

If your columns are not named you might try something like,

```
        foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        column.ColumnName = columnNameArray[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Or ideally you would read into table.columns.add() when you hit that part of the csv

Comment: Why are you gonna waste time and resources populating a `DataSet` with useless data, if you can pre-filter them? Just by omitting the columns on the `GridView` is not a good solution.

Comment: @MelanciaUk I agree with you, but I need alittle help with the syntax of the filter you are talking about. Major brain fart happening here for me.....

Comment: The compute time to read them is pretty insignificant unless he is only using a tiny percentage of a huge table. Controlling your display is important anyway, and frankly I use unshown datakeys in gridview to simplify what the user sees and enable background operations based on selected rows or row double clicks all the time. Who says its useless data? He asked how to hide them and not omit them. Why would you waste your time reading through a bunch of data finding out what an appropriate filter would be before seeing how fast it was and making sure optimization was relevant?

Comment: @Fraser please show me the syntax of what you are talking about or direct me to a snippet, even add on to my code. Please less talk more action, please.

Comment: @Fraser, seeing from this side I agree with you.

Comment: Now that we all agree, please show me an example of code instead of sending a link to msdn site which I have been reading for that pass couple days with nothing but confusion and stress

Comment: the type of column depends on the data, bound is probably fine. If the datatable has named columns you reference those in the datafield part of the asp:boundfield tag that connects the table column to the grid column. If a table column is not bound it will not show up unless you have told the grid to auto generate columns. I will update the asp tags in the answer

Comment: @Fraser I managed to hide the rest of the columns with no constance values, thank you. Now my next question is, how do I make them selectable rows.

Comment: easiest answer <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" commandname="Select" headertext="Select Customer" text="Select"/> See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx